# Should I setup x86_64 system on Atom 230?

Tags: 64-bit, intel-atom, 32-vs-64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [32-bit vs. 64-bit systems](https://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems)

I've got mini-ITX motherboard (945GCLF, afair) and I always setup only 32-bit OS on it.
But few weeks ago my father told me that I should use 64-bit OS for this processor.

What can I get from changing architecture? Will it speed up something?

In general, does it *matter* which architecture I use?

P.S. I've got 2 GB RAM and use Archlinux.

Comment: Related: [32-bit Ubuntu or 64-bit w/Intel Atom D510 w/4GB RAM?](http://superuser.com/questions/144753/32-bit-ubuntu-or-64-bit-w-intel-atom-d510-w-4gb-ram?rq=1)

Comment: well, with only using 2gb Ram, you won't get the benefit of seeing 4gb or more by using a 64 bit OS.  But really, it depends on the software you use.  If you don't have a burning need for 64 bit software, you most likely don't need a 64bit OS.